# avoid raising exception when no permission in claim based security

Tags: .net, security, .net-4.5, claims-based-identity

How can I suppress exception thrown from ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess even if it returns false.

To be more explanatory, I am trying to create a collection of objects. Some objects are allowed to user and some not. I just want to ignore the exception and load the collection with allowed objects in claim based security model.

But right now my code is throwing can exception.

Any idea how can i suppress the exception raised.

Answer (score 0):

ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess does not throw. Could you elaborate?

Comment: yes but when it returns false the security exception is thrown. is there any way to suppress that?

Comment: That depends how you call it - how do you call it?